# The image from the form does not load

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a website for each node.js/express. I made a form and it works well. However, when you add the line "enctype = "composite/form data", everything stops working (instead of the values of the input fields, "Avoid" is added to the database).

Handlebars:

```
    <form action="/target/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="name">Имя:</label>
        <input name="name"><br><br>
      <label for="age">Возраст:</label>
        <input name="age"><br><br>
      <label for="comm">Комментарий:</label>
      <input name="salary"><br><br>
      <label for="img">Картинка:</label>
      <input type="file" name="f">
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Node:

```
mongoClient.connect(async function(error, mongo) {
    if (!error) {
        let db = mongo.db('NODE_db');
        let coll = db.collection('users');
app.post('/target/', urlencodedParser, async function(req, res) {
            //Validation
            if (req.body.name == '' || req.body.age == '' || req.body.comm == ''){
                res.status(400).json({mess: "fill fields"})
            }
            else {
                await coll.insertOne(req.body);
                res.redirect('/')
            }
        });
} else {
    console.error(error);
}
});
```

Comment: There's quite a few errors here, a bit much to sum up quickly but your Express (app.post) is in the wrong location, it should be before you call for MongoClient Query and with that too you should consider a pool and setting connection limit otherwise you could actually be hurting performance and possibly be stacking connections unnecessary (eventually erroring you).

Comment: Additionally client looks fine, just the server-side is coded wrong; you can look into multer for Node.JS to see if explains the process better.

Comment: You have small bug in first line => I think it should be method="post"